# List to Map, with key as the first character and values as words corresponding to the first letter key character

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I've got a List, for ex. {cat, ball, bat, cup, add, ant}, which I'm trying to convert into Map with key as the first character available in words of the List, and values as the corresponding words in the List.

i.e

a->add,ant

b->ball,bat

c->cat,cup

The output as Map. It would be much helpful if I could get some guidance.

Comment: did you try anything? what issues are you having?

Comment: are there any words beginning with an upper case?

Answer (score 1):

Use 
`Map<Character, List<String>>` 
Where key is Character and value is list of all words from that Character. 
While adding character you have to rembmber that 'A' and 'a' is different key.
To get first character

- If 'A' and 'a' treated as different then

  **key = <String>.charAt(0)**
- If 'A' and 'a' treated as same

  **key = <String>.toUpperCase().charAt(0)**

Answer (score 1):

Using pure Java:

```
List<String> words = 
    new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("cat", "ball", "bat", "cup", "add", "ant"));
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap();
    for(String word: words){
        String firstChar = String.valueOf(word.charAt(0));
        if (map.get(firstChar) == null){
            map.put(firstChar, new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(word)));
        }
        else{
            map.get(firstChar).add(word);
        }
    }
```

or better way use Guava library as Aniket Thakur suggested

Comment: just wanted to know why you chose key as string as we can chose Character as a key

Answer (score 0):

> guidance

Use `Map<String, List<String>>` and [`substring(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method

Answer (score 0):

You can either `use Map<String, List<String>>` but I would suggest use

`Multimap : Keys need not be unique.But same key can have same values`.

Even better is

```
SetMultimap : Same as Multimap but no duplicate values for a given key. 
Duplicate keys are allowed.
```

All these clases are in Googles [guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

Example

```
  Multimap<String, String> myMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

  // Adding some key/value
  myMultimap.put("a", "add");
  myMultimap.put("a", "ant");
  myMultimap.put("b", "ball");
  myMultimap.put("b", "bat");
```

Do explore the APIs in the link I provided above.

Answer (score 0):

In java 8 we can solve this with precise code:

```
Map map = nameList.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors
            .toMap(x -> x.charAt(0),
                x -> nameList.stream().filter(y -> y.startsWith(String.valueOf(x.charAt(0))))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()),
                    (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue, HashMap::new));
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work if there are only words in your list, beginning with a lower case.

```
public static Map<String, List<String>> arrayToList(String[] words) {
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        for (int n = 97; n <= 122; n++) {
            ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                if (words[i].charAt(0) == n) {
                    wordList.add(words[i]);
                    map.put("" + words[i].charAt(0), wordList);
                }
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
```

Comment: Why we need words[i].toCharArray() as we only need first character there is a function called charAt(index).

Comment: But still insted of calling words[i].charAt(0) again you can use temp char. can you please calculate complexity of your code you are unnessary using 2 for loop. and  will this effect if you move map.put("" + words[i].charAt(0), wordList); outside your for loop.

Comment: the solution of shevchik is far better than mine, so have a look at it.